# Complex Function and type delegates in C#

Tags: c#, types, delegates

I am a novice/intermediate C# developer trying to accomplish a task I would be comfortable doing in C.

Basically, I'm getting XML requests that I need to respond to with a corresponding response. The request/response pairs are well defined in a structure like:

- "Method1Request" receives "Method1Response"
- "Method2Request" receives "Method2Response"
- ...

So, I'm going to create functions in my class called "Method1", "Method2",... that take parameters "Method1Request", "Method2Request",... and return "Method1Response", "Method2Response",...

In code, the function declarations would look like this, and the accompanying code is varied:

- Mtehod1Response Method1(Method1Request);
- Method2Response Method2(Method2Request);
- ...

All of the function responses will immediately be serialized into XML, so, theoretically, the functions could all be like this, and could write the result to the private string variable "response":
void Method1(Method1Request)
void Method2(Method2Request)
...

Anyway, what I would like to do is "sample" the XML (already have this working), to find out what type of request it is  and use a case statement to, essentially, run the appropriate function on the request and , therefore, generate the correct response.

So, I need to create a function that does all of the steps that remain the same around calling those specific functions. It would basically be structured like this (!PSEUDO CODE!):

```
void ProcessRequestResponse(Type RequestType, Type ResponseType, Method MethodToRun)
{
    ...create serializers for RequestType and ResponseType...
    ...deserialize XML into RequestType...
    [ResponseType] [MethodToRun]([RequestType]);
    ...serialize ResponseType into XML...
    ...store XML as variable in class...
}
```

I just have no idea how to actually create that function and have it know what function to run with which types. I looked into using the delegate "Func" methods, but I don't see a way to define them with types that are unknown at the time of creation.

Any direction on how to solve this would be appreciated. I don't think I need to type all of that code for each of my 15+ cases (hopefully!) and manage near identical instances of the *almost same* code.

Comment: You don't need to use serialize to generate xml.  Instead where you have dynamic tags I would use either XmlElement or XElement (xml linq) to generate the xml.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the Generics route, implementing some helper class and resolving the request-handling strategy using a configuration object (can be a simple Dictionary).

If you have 15+ request types, I would prefer having 15+ alternative classes, each implementing the corresponding handling strategy.

WARNING: just some throwaway example code, but should give you an head start.

```
// Define a weakly typed interface, to be called
// by the invoking code.
public interface IRequestHandler
{
  public string HandleRequest(string xmlRequest);
}

// Defines a generic handler, accepting two type parameters, one
// for the request, one for the response.
public abstract class RequestHandler<RequestType, ResponseType> : IRequestHandler
{

  public XmlSerializer GetRequestSerializer()
  {
    return GetSerializer(typeof(RequestType));
  }

  public XmlSerializer GetResponseSerializer()
  {
    return GetSerializer(typeof(ResponseType));
    // an alternative, depending upon your deserialization library,
    // could be:
    // return GetSerializer<ResponseType>();
  }

  public XmlSerializer GetSerializer(Type dataType)
  {
    ... resolve based on type.
  }

  public string HandleRequest(string xmlRequest)
  {
    if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

    var requestSerializer = GetRequestSerializer();
    var typedRequest = requestSerializer.Deserialize(xmlRequest) as RequestType;
    // response is a ResponseType
    var response = ProcessRequest(typedRequest);

    var responseSerializer = GetResponseSerializer();

    return responseSerializer.Serialize(response);
  }

  protected abstract ResponseType ProcessRequest(RequestType request);
}

// One handler implementation
// you can just declare the class and RequestHandler inheritance,
// and then right click and ask Visual Studio to "Implement abstract members"
public class ActualRequestHandler : RequestHandler<ActualRequest, ActualResponse>
{
  protected ActualResponse ProcessRequest(ActualRequest request)
  {
    // ... do your processing
  }
}

// One handler implementation
public class AnotherRequestHandler : RequestHandler<AnotherRequest, AnotherResponse>
{
  protected AnotherResponse ProcessRequest(AnotherRequest request)
  {
    // ... do your processing
  }
}
```

A simple configuration could be a static dictionary in your external processor class:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<IRequestHandler>> _strategyGetter = new Dictionary<Type, IRequestHandler>()
{
  {typeof(ActualRequest), () => new ActualRequestHandler()},
  {typeof(AnotherRequest), () => new AnotherRequestHandler()}
};
```

And finally, your global code:

```
Type requestType = ... your existing code processing the string request ...
Func<IRequestHandler> handlerFactoryMethod;
if(_strategyGetters.TryGetValue(requestType, out handlerFactoryMethod))
{
  var handler = handlerFactoryMethod();
  var responseString = handler(request);

  // ... do what you want with responseString ...
}
else
{
  // seems the request was not recognized.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Reflection is a way to solve your problem. Possible example:

Here are your different functions:

```
class Methodes
{
  bool func1(bool a) { ...}
  int func2(double b) { ... }
}
```

First you have to get all [MethodInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.methodinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (all available methodes) via reflection:

```
MethodInfo[] AvailableMethodes = typeof(Methodes).GetMethods();
```

Now you can search the methode you want using a loop through your available methodes. Use the [GetParameters()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ReturnType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if the parameters an types are correct. If you have a match, call a the methode with the [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
foreach (MethodInfo AvailableMethode in AvailableMethodes)
{
  if (AvaliableMethode.ReturnType.ToString() == "TheReturnTypeYouWished") //Check your parameters also (use GetParameters)
  {
    //Call the method if you have a match
    AvaliableMethode.Invoke(AInstanceOfMethodes, YourParameter(s));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# and most other strongly-typed OO languages implement method [overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx).  The runtime will automatically dispatch to the correct method of a class based on parameter type, e.g.

```
ResponseType1 handleRequest(RequestType1 request) { ... }    
ResponseType2 handleRequest(RequestType2 request) { ... }
```

I believe it will work in this case, but can be problematic if there is ambiguity in parameter types (i.e. one method's parameter is a superclass of another's).

Reflection will work but it bypasses compile-time checks and should generally be used only as a last resort.

You can declare a generic class or delegate e.g. `RequestHandler<RequestType, ReturnType>` and extend it with concrete implementations but the problem of dispatching based on the parameter type is still left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If design patterns interests you then you can use flavor of Chain of Responsibility(COR) with Command Pattern to redirect the request to it's typed handler.

Design base skeletons -

```
abstract class RequestBase  { }

abstract class ResponseBase { }

/// <summary>
/// Base class which will handle the request if the derived type is responsible otherwise 
/// send request to success handler in chain.
/// </summary>
internal abstract class HandlerBase<TRequest, TResponse> // contraints
    where TResponse : ResponseBase
    where TRequest : RequestBase
{
    HandlerBase<TRequest, TResponse> nextHandler;

    protected HandlerBase(HandlerBase<TRequest, TResponse> nextHandler)
    {
        this.nextHandler = nextHandler;
    }

    public TResponse Execute(TRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        try
        {
            if (this.IsResponsible(request))
                return this.InternalExecute(request);
            else
                return this.nextHandler.InternalExecute(request);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // log exception and rethrow or convert then throw.
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected abstract TResponse InternalExecute(TRequest request);

    protected abstract bool IsResponsible(TRequest request);
}
```

Now realize your concrete requests and their respective handlers e.g.

```
class RequestA : RequestBase { }
class ResponseA : ResponseBase { }
class RequestB : RequestBase { }
class ResponseB : ResponseBase { }

internal class RequestAHandler : HandlerBase<RequestBase, ResponseBase>
{
    public RequestAHandler(HandlerBase<RequestBase, ResponseBase> nextHandler) : base(nextHandler)  {  }

    protected override RequestB InternalExecute(RequestBase request)
    {
        // do what ever RequestA handler shall do
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override bool IsResponsible(RequestBase request)
    {
        return request is RequestA;
    }
}

internal class RequestBHandler : HandlerBase<RequestBase, ResponseBase>
{
    public RequestBHandler(HandlerBase<RequestBase, ResponseBase> nextHandler) : base(nextHandler)  {  }

    protected override RequestB InternalExecute(RequestA request)
    {
        // do what ever RequestB handler shall do
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override bool IsResponsible(RequestBase request)
    {
        return request is RequestB;
    }
}
```

Finally putting everything together. We have a COR base class which would invoke the responsible handler to manipulate the request. But we need a dispatcher which knows the chain or handlers and can pass the incoming request.

```
class Dispatcher
{
    // cache chained instances of handlers
    private static HandlerBase<RequestBase, ResponseBase> handler = RegisterHandlers();

    public static ResponseBase Dispatch(RequestBase request)
    {
        return handler.Execute(request);
    }

    private static HandlerBase<RequestBase, ResponseBase> RegisterHandlers()
    {
        // Build chain
        HandlerBase<RequestBase, ResponseBase> contextChain = new RequestAHandler(null);
        contextChain = new RequestBHandler(contextChain);
        // register new handlers here e.g.
        // contextChain = new RequestXHandler(contextChain);

        return contextChain;
    }
}
```

Usage -

```
var response = (ResponseA)Dispatcher.Dispatch(new RequestA());
```

you might be thinking it's too much of boiler plate code. But that's how the frameworks are built(with boilerplating). Now if you want to add a new Handler of request type of X you just need implement `RequestX`, `ResponseX`, `RequestXHandler` and Register it with dispatcher.

**Note-** Write unit tests to validate the system. I wrote this code on an online C# editor ;) Cheers!!